# How to plot a barycentric line

Tags: plotting, graphics, function-construction, geometry, simplex

I want to plot a barycentric function on an equilateral triangle (ternary plot). For example

```
f1 = {Abs[Sin[x]], Mod[x, 2], Abs[Cos[x]]};
```

At the moment I evaluate a list of data points and join them with a line

```
Show[{b3["PlotAxis"],ListPlot[b3["Data"][Range[0,100,1/#],f1],Joined->True]}]&/@{1,10,100}
```

[image]

Where b3 is:

```
b3 = GetBarycentric[3];
b3["Axis"] = {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};
b3["Convert"][{a_, b_, c_}, axis_: b3["Axis"]] := Module[{
    abc = {a, b, c}, sum = Total[{a, b, c}]},
   Piecewise[{{ (axis[[1]] a + axis[[2]] b)/sum, sum > 0}, {axis[[2]], sum <= 0}}]];
b3["Data"][values_, rlines_] := b3["Convert"][#] & /@ Transpose[rlines /. x -> values]
b3["PlotAxis"] := Graphics[{Thin, Line[{#1, #2, #3, #1}]}] & @@ b3["Axis"];
```

I can not use listplots 'Joined->True', because lines are intermittent.

[image]

How can I transform the function and plot it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A ternary plot is a plot on the nonnegative unit simplex in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so apply an affine change of basis (and rescale `f1` to be sure its values lie on the simplex):

```
ClearAll[f1];
f1[x_] := {Abs[Sin[x]], Mod[x, 2], Abs[Cos[x]]};

With[{xyToTernary = {{0, 1, 1/2}, {0, 0, Sqrt[3]/2}}}, 
 ParametricPlot[xyToTernary . (f1[x] / Total[f1[x]]), {x, 1, 3^5}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  Prolog -> {White, EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Plot]

Due to the nature of your function, it would be a good idea to break it at integral values of `x` by including the option `Exclusions -> Range[3^5]`:

[image: Plot 2]

If you would like to visualize the 3D to 2D relationship inherent in these plots, you can ask *Mathematica* to do the projecting for you (but the 2D quality is degraded):

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]},  
  ViewVector -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {-8, -8, -8}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewCenter -> {1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, 
  ViewAngle -> \[Pi]/2,  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}],
 ParametricPlot3D[f1[x] / Total[f1[x]], {x, 1, 3^5}, 
  Exclusions -> Range[3^5]], Axes -> {True, True, True}
 ]
```

(Image not shown.)

Comment: Probably cleaner to use `Normalize[f1[x], Total]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Exclusions` to exclude points where your function is discontinuous. For example

```
Plot[Evaluate[f1/Total[f1]], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> Range[0, 10, 2]]
```

[image: screenshot]

and

```
triangle = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};

ParametricPlot[f1.triangle/Total[f1], {x, 0, 200}, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], Polygon[triangle]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> .1, Axes -> False,
 Exclusions -> Range[0, 200, 2]]
```

[image: triangle]

**Edit**

As whuber pointed out in the comment below, the plot looks a bit ragged near the bottom and right edge. You can correct this by increasing the number of plot points and the maximum number of recursions, e.g.

```
ParametricPlot[f1.triangle/Total[f1], {x, 0, 200}, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], Polygon[triangle]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> .04,
 Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 Exclusions -> Range[0, 200, 2]]
```

Comment: I was editing my post to point out the advantage of `Exclusions` when this reply appeared. :-)  Notice that with this function you need to exclude *all* integers, not just the even ones.  (Look at the detail along the upper right and bottom edges.)

Comment: @whuber I was just trying to fix that :-) The function isn't actually discontinuous there -- just the derivative. You can correct it by cranking up the number of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.

Comment: Yep...but I suspect it's more efficient just to declare the cusps explicitly (when you know them, as in this case) rather than asking for a finer mesh.

Comment: @whuber hmm, you got a point there